# Distributivity within cosets and intersections

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $H$, $K$ are subgroups of $G$. Given $x\in G$, is it true that $x(H\cap K)=xH\cap xK$?

Comment: Yes, and this has nothing to do with the fact that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because as $H\cap K\subset H,K$, $x(H\cap K)\subset xH, xK$, hence $x(H\cap K)\subset xH\cap xK$.

Conversely, if $xh=xk\enspace(h\in H, k\in K$, from the cancellation rule in groups, we deduce $h=k$, which therefore belongs to $H\cap K$, $xh\in x H\cap K$.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. Consider an elt t in the intersection, then x*t belongs to xH and xK, so it belongs to their intersection. If you assume that an elt p belongs the the intersection of xH and xK, then, p = xj, for some j in both H and K, so xj belongs to x(H int K).